# Configuring a service to be started under Local Service account from command line

Tags: configuration, command-line-interface, windows-service

How can this problem be solved?

I know there is a `sc` utility, but I don't know how to assign the Local Service account to the `obj` parameter (because of the spaces in the name), and how to assign a blank password (I assume Local Service account has a blank password) to the `password` parameter.

Comment: What version of Windows is this?

Comment: I'm testing this on Win7 but it should apply to XP as well and corresponding server versions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work:  SC CONFIG MyService binPath=c:\myprogram.exe obj=".\LocalSystem" password=""

Comment: Look at some of the examples here:

http://ss64.com/nt/sc.html

Comment: Thank you. I took that last example, and played with it and finally got it to work with `SC.EXE CONFIG MyServiceName obj= "\Local Service" password= ""`

Answer (score 8):

To be clear, the proper command is:

```
SC CONFIG MYSERVICENAMEHERE obj="NT AUTHORITY\LocalService" password= ""
```

Comment: For me (Windows 10) it only worked without the password property

Answer (score 4):

@Amir's answer was the closest, but spaces are needed after the equal signs. If you view the help for SC.EXE, you'll see:

```
NOTE: The option name includes the equal sign.
      A space is required between the equal sign and the value.
```

So to get this to work under the real Local Service account on Windows 2012 R2, the following worked:

```
SC.EXE CREATE TheServiceName start= auto binPath= "C:\path\to\TheService.exe" obj= "NT AUTHORITY\LocalService" password= ""
```

When I tried...

```
obj= "\Local Service"
```

...it didn't get set to run under the real Local Service account.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding previous comment, be aware that [Local System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Local Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is not the same account. [Local Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has much less rights.